# React Native import firebase 'auth' and 'firestore'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting errors when I try to simply load the auth and firestore from firebase.

Error message:

> TypeError: (0, _app.initializeApp) is not a function. (In '(0, _app.initializeApp)(firebaseConfig)', '(0, _app.initializeApp)' is undefined)

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "KEY",
  authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "app",
  storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1293821378",
  appId: "5647"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = app.auth();

export { db, auth }
```

Also when I try to import the auth from another file I try this:

```
import { auth } from '../firebase';
```

Comment: What is your Firebase version?

Comment: "firebase": "8.2.3"

Comment: You are using syntax of new [Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) which was added from v9. So try updating Firebase to latest version `npm i firebase@latest` and also use `getAuth()` to initialize auth `import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth"` `const auth = getAuth()`

Comment: I want to use the version 8, can you help me with that?

Comment: No, it should work I’m just doing something wrong here and I don’t know what it is, I was able to load the auth but when I try to load also the firestore it didn’t go well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Firebase version `<9.0.0` which only supports name-spaced SDK, then use the older imports only and not the modular syntax. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth }
```

Also makes sure you are referring to `Web (name-spaced)` tab in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, Thanks!
So what's the point of the const app? I see we're not using it.
Can you also show me how load the firestore on my other file? something like
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

Comment: Just import DB and keep using v8 syntax that you are referring to. GetDocs is v9

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help, I upgraded to 9.